# Optimize a function with a high payload and requests

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

As part of a large project I wrote a function that needs to fetch a large amount of data from an external website.
The problem is that it sends a large amount of requests in the TCP protocol with a relatively high payload.
I would appreciate your opinion and methods for optimization.

I thought it might be possible to split the requests into several treads on the same process. For example Tread1 will fetch pages 0-1000
Tread2 1000-2000
And so on.

In addition, since the request use TCP protocol, I keep the session open to avoid the 3 hand shake, but I'm not sure that I implemented it correctly.

```
def get_data(url, payload, df):
    page_no = 0
    pages = 5200
    session = requests.Session()
    while page_no < pages:
        try:
            response = session.post(url, json=payload)
            json_data = response.json()
            new_df = pd.DataFrame(json_data['AllResults'])
            if new_df.shape[0] != 0:
                df = pd.concat([df, new_df], ignore_index=True)
        except:
            print(f"Error: {page_no}")        
        page_no += 1
        payload['PageNo'] = page_no

    return df
```

payload:

```
payload = {
    "MoreAssestsType": None,
    "FillterRoomNum": 0,
    "GridDisplayType": 0,
    "ResultLable": "city",
    "ResultType": 1,
    "ObjectID": "5000",
    "ObjectIDType": "text",
    "ObjectKey": "UNIQ_ID",
    "X": 180428.31832654,
    "Y": 665726.5550939,
    "Gush": "",
    "Parcel": "",
    "showLotParcel": False,
    "showLotAddress": False,
    "OriginalSearchString": "city",
    "CurrentLavel": 2,
    "Navs": [],
    "QueryMapParams": {
        "QueryToRun": None,
        "QueryObjectID": "5000",
        "QueryObjectType": "number",
        "QueryObjectKey": "SETL_CODE",
        "QueryDescLayerID": "KSHTANN_SETL_AREA",
        "SpacialWhereClause": True,
    },
    "isHistorical": False,
    "PageNo": 1,
    "OrderByFilled": "DEALDATETIME",
    "OrderByDescending": True,
    "Distance": 0
}
```

Comment: Before turning to magical attempts, you should really-really look into if you can request for larger pages and thus reduce the amount of them.

Comment: @tevemadar I didn't write but I already ran the function for 28 hours until I got all the data.
The function ran well without any problems and returned all the required data.

Comment: That's okay. What I meant is looking into if you could reduce the number of requests from 5200 to (say) 520, and get 10x larger answers, that would reduce the number of times you send out `payload`. Having the same 5200 requests, just scattered in multiple threads, will still send `payload` 5200 times.

Comment: @tevemadar 
I dug a bit in the payload and didn't find a way. I'll share the payload here, maybe you'll see something I didn't see.

Comment: Here I also see `PageNo` only. There may or may not be something else, which is just left as default here, like `PageSize`, `ItemsPerPage`, or something like them. While I found the site where this goes, it's full Hebrew, so I have no chance to find if there's relevant documentation.